# Checking that each matrix element is different

Tags: matlab

Every element in my matrix is integer, I want to check if all of these elements are different from each other. Is there any shortcut for this or how can I solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `X` be your matrix. There are several ways to do what you want. Either of the following gives `true` or `false`:

- `all(diff(sort(X(:))))`
- `numel(unique(X))==numel(X)`
- `all(pdist(X(:)))` (requires Statistics Toolbox)

Comment: The 3rd one is likely the most expensive computationally and also memory-wise. Of the other two, I have no intuition whatsoever which one is most efficient.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I bet on the first, but no idea :-)

Comment: I used your first suggestion and solved my problem. Thanks a lot